# How to keep track of line number in files when its being updated continuosuly

Tags: c#, filereader

We are pushing IIS Log files via API to DB for monitoring via SPLUNK but we are sending the duplicate data since our C# job runs every five minutes and it sends all the lines

```
        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
        new System.IO.StreamReader(filepath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
          System.Console.WriteLine(line);
        counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
        System.Console.WriteLine("There were {0} lines.", counter);
        // Suspend the screen.  
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem ?

Comment: Add an ID field to the data.  I would recommend making each entry in log Xml format.  The xml will not be well formed meaning there are an array of elements at the root but it makes it easy to read fields in the results.  Using Xml in log files are very common and make it very easy to parse.  See following Code Project : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28752/Use-XML-for-Log-Files

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

1. Before the run starts, store in a file, say file1, the number of lines in the log file. This is a onetime step.
2. Before the while loop in the code, from file1 read the number of lines into a variable, say lastCount
3. Change line System.Console.WriteLine(line) to the following:

   > if (counter > lastCount) 
   >       System.Console.WriteLine(line);
4. After the while loop, store the value of the counter in file1